# Is it possible to gain access to an embedded Flash video's parameters that is embedded on a site you don't own via a browser extension with JS/HTML5?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, html, flash

I'd like to gain read only access to the following parameters of embedded Flash videos located on sites that I do not own through my own custom browser extension/add-on:

- **Time location of playback head** (so I can display the current time in the browser extension via HTML5/JavaScript)
- **Frames** (so I can make capture them to an image file, save it and display image in browser extension)
- **Original Dimensions in pixels** (so I can display the original video dimensions via JS/HTML5 in browser extension)

**Is this possible by using Javascript and HTML5 from a browser extension?**

Would I have to use something like the SWFObject Javascript API http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this, unless the content was specifically designed for it.
If you were a content provider, would you want third party companies to be able to just embed your videos into their own pages, easily take snapshots and/or fiddle around with the way the movie is displayed?

All SWF files are protected from access from all other domains, unless the author explicitly allows it.  Also, methods and properties have to be made available to JavaScript.  If you don't own the code, you can't do any of these things...

Also, FLV movies are usually shown inside a player SWF file.  So even if you were able to access the properties of the file embedded into the HTML page, you wouldn't get to the original video content, but only to the skin around it.